# AVL tree insertion question

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

I am watching a lecture from IIT about data structures ( Dr.naveen garg ) About AVL tree.

[image: Screen shot]

My Question : Why the height of T2 can't be (h-1)?

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't something earlier in the lecture where he was mentioning that the current case is for inserting into the shallower subtree?  Did he say what the heights of the four labeled trees in the diagram are?  Also, the slide says "x remains balanced"; if that is the case, ht(T_2) can't be h-1 because ht(T_1) after the insertion is h+1 and so that is unbalanced.

Comment: X remains balanced is the right question i mean .. why must X remain balanced ?

Comment: I don't know.  Did he say anything about that in the lecture?  It could be that he assumes the insertion under `x` will be a recursive AVL insertion, and so it would be rebalanced if necessary after the raw insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that the tree is balanced after the insertion WITHOUT rotation.

If rotation occured - it's a different case and you deal with it with ROTATION, I figure it out from `"Since X remains balanced.."` this is the assumption, and we are showing in here that the tree stays balanced only in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if ht(T2) were to be (h-1) like you said, then the tree would be unbalanced AFTER insertion. Which is not part of the ASSUMPTION in the question.

Because the balance factor of x will now be 2. Thus a rotation would have to take place.